# Any idea about inserting html to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to insert piece of my html code(which is actually working in my local html file) in SharePoint. But it is not accepting all my tags which are there in the code, for eg: 'style' tag.
Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Your question is unclear: How are you trying to inject code? Where are you trying to inject code? How have you tried to inject the code? Why are you not using a CSS file for the style?
Marked your question as "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: Am sorry for not being clear. First thing, do you understand what I mean by SharePoint? because am very new to SharePoint tool !

Comment: SharePoint is a extensible CMS developed by Microsoft. Of course I know what you mean by the term "SharePoint". I programmed with it for several years

Comment: Thats Cool. I have no idea about it. Its been first day for me. Ok my point is how do I insert CSS file in SharePoint ? When I'm trying to insert css tags into "Edit Source"  option (here is the place I'm inserting my html code as it is), few of the properties are not working. For eg: the **position** property is getting removed as soon as I copy my code into Edit Source

Comment: Where are you pressing "Edit source"? What are you trying to edit? An ASPX page? A master page? Are you using Sharepoint Designer? Do you want your CSS file to be loaded on all pages?

Comment: I don't have access to SharePoint designer. I am actually inserting the code in web part. No I want only one page to be effected with my CSS, not all. If possible I'll share the screen where I'm doing all this stuff

Comment: So you have a webpart with HTML content, where you are trying to insert your style? If yes I highly doubt that this is possible. The reason for this are security concerns. If you would be able to insert javascript and style tags into a HTML-Webpart it would be so easy for someone to inject a virus into a sharepoint site or change its appearance. To prevent this Microsoft prevents you from executing javascript and inserting css-style definitions into the HTML-webpart.
What exactly do you need the style tag for? what are you trying to style?

Comment: I have many linked lists in my code where the style properties for all the <li> tags is same. So I'm writing a common code in style tag which we generally write in html. And also I want to use position:absolute property in my code but it is not working too.

Comment: Which version of sharepoint are you using? Sharepoint 2013?`

Comment: Ya, it is SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open page for edit. Then from "Media and Content" group choose "Script Editor" web part. And then click Edit Snipper and paste your html code there. 

You can also use Content Editor web part and provide link to your html code.

If you want to change style for whole SharePoint you can modify Master Page or providing Alternate CSS for exiting one (this is possible in Central Administration).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But even the snippet is doing the same. It is ignoring few of the CSS properties. And for the latter one, I don't have access. And I don't want to modify the whole SP. just a single page

Comment: I just did a test. In snippet editor I wrote: <style>body { background-color: #00ff00  !important; } </style> and it is working fine. Try also with "!important".

Comment: Ya your first reply worked. Sorry I was confused about the term Script Editor as there were many options to paste the html code. Anyways thanks for your reply :)